# Alternate way to delete a node in circular linked in python

Tags: python, linked-list, circular-list

Here is my code to delete any node from circular linked list:

```
def delete_node(head, value):
    p = head
    if p is None:
        return None
    if p.value == value and p.next == p:
        return None
    while p.value != value:
        p = p.next
        if p.next is head and p.value != value:
            return head
    p.value = p.next.value
    if p.next == head:
        head = p
    p.next = p.next.next
    return head
    pass
```

Is there any other alternate way to delete a node from circular linked list?

Comment: Why is this method insufficient?

Comment: this method is not insufficient iam checking for alternate way to do it but it is not getting me any idea can you tell me? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def delete(head, value):
    curr = head
    prev = curr.next
    while prev.next != head:
        prev = prev.next

    if curr.value == value:
        prev.next = curr.next

    curr = curr.next
    prev = prev.next
    while curr.value != value and curr != head:
        curr = curr.next
        prev = prev.next

    if curr.value == value:
        prev.next = curr.next
```